# Using PCRE2 regex with repeating groups to find email addresses

Tags: regex, repeat, regex-group, kleene-star

I need to find all email addresses with an arbitrary number of alphanumeric words, separated through a period. To test the regex, I'm using the website https://regex101.com/.

The structure of a valid email addresses is `word1.word2.wordN@word1.word2.wordN.word`.

The regex `/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm` finds all email addresses included in the document string, but also includes invalid addresses like `........@....com`, if present.

I tried to group the repeating parts by using round brackets and a Kleene star, but that causes the regex engine to collapse.

Invalid regex:

`/([a-zA-Z0-9]+.?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+@([a-zA-Z0-9]+.?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm`

Although there are many posts concerning regex groups, I was unable to find an explanation, why the regex engine fails. It seems that the engine gets stuck, while trying to find a match.

How can I avoid this problem, and what is the correct solution?

Comment: Like this? `\w+(?:\.+\w+)*@\w+(?:\.+\w+)*` https://regex101.com/r/pnHwxC/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue that caused you troubles is:
`.` (outside of `[]`) matches **any** character,
you probably meant to specify `\.` instead (only matches literal dot character).

Also there is no need to make it optional with `?`, because the non-dot part of your regex will just match with the alphanumerical characters anyway.

I also reduced the right part (`x*x` is the same as `x+`), added a case-insensitive flag and ended up with this:

```
/([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]+@([a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]+/gmi
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! After all it was just an escape sequence problem...